# x500 and LegacyExchangeDN

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2003

We have exchange 2010, there are several users, who were migrated from exchange 2003. We encountered several problems with x500 records. We modified x500 records to the right form, but after few weeks wrong x500 records were created again. We find out that this have something common with LegacyExchangeDN. We can see that LegacyExchangeDN is pointed to new "Exchange Administrative group". Could you explain me why new x500 records were created (I think it is somehow synchronized with the LegacyExchangeDN) Do you know what could be responsible for creation of x500 records automatically? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the X500 addresses are being created by a Recipient Policy.  Check the policies that you have present in your organization - most likely one of them is set to enforce the creation of an X500 address.

However, the legacyExchangeDN will still be present on those accounts.. so if the value that it's being set to is a problem, then you'll need to address that problem directly.  Can you clarify on that point?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I checked our email-address policy and x500 is not configured there. There is set only 3 SMTP records and one x400 records so the policy could not create x500 record.

Comment: Problem is that we want to point mailbox to old Environment. When we checked the account the first time we could see that there was x500 record, which was pointing to new "Exchange administrative group", so we deleted this record and created x500 record to the old environment (Old Exchange Administrative group). After few weeks there is new x500 record which is pointing to the new environment. We think that this record could be created due to legacyExchangeDN, because it is pointing to new environment. Maybe we should change it.